# how to write test script(java) to scroll to a particular cell and perform a click on that cell using appium 1.6.4?

Tags: uitableview, automated-tests, appium, ios10.2

I have a tableview with a number of tableview cells. Within each cell there are 2 buttons.

What I need is I need to write a test script (in java) to scroll to a particular cell and perform click action in a button which is within the cell.

I am using **appium (version 1.6.4)**, so the `scrollto` method is deprecated.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If some elements have accessibility-id you can scroll to these elements by:

```
WebElement element = this.findElementByIosNsPredicate("name matches '"+ elementName + "'");
new TouchAction(driver).press(element, 0, 0).moveTo(element, 0, 0).release().perform();
```

elementName - accessibility id

And after it tap on elements in view.